# how to determine a matrix has a single eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the jordan form of the matrix
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 2 & 2\\
 1 & -2 & -1 & -1\\
 -2 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Hint: check that the matrix A has a single eigenvalue, and $trace(A) = 0$.

How can I check that the matrix has a single eigenvalue without using the determinant?

That's what I managed to do so far:

Let $G$ the Jordan form of $A$, using the hint that there is a single eigenvalue:
$$trace(A) = 0\implies 0 = trace(A) = trace(G) = 4a \implies a = 0$$

meaning that theres a single eigenvalue which is zero.

Then the characteristic polynomial is $A^4$  and the minimal polynomial is $A^3$.

Then:
$G = diag\{J_3(0), J_1(0)\}$

But how do I prove that there is a single eigenvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank is 2 (the first two columns span the image) and trace is zero. If there is one non-zero eigenvalue $a$, there is another non-zero eigenvalue $-a$. Hence the image would be spanned by the two eigenvectors of the non-zero eigenvalues and the same would automatically hold for all powers of $A$. But the first column is contained in the kernel and in the image of the matrix, hence the rank of $A^2$ will be at most $1$ (since $e_1$ is in the kernel of $A^2$, but not in the kernel of $A$), contradiction to the conclusion above!

Answer (score 0):

Since the characteristic polynomial is $\chi_A (x) = x^4 $, this tells you that all eigenvalues are zero.

A matrix satisfies its characteristic polynomial by the Cayley Hamilton theorem, hence $A^4 = 0$. If $v$ is a non zero eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then $0 = A^4 v = \lambda^4 v$ and so $\lambda = 0$.

Comment: Why the downvote? Really, please tell me.

Comment: Since the OP asked how to figure out, using the fewest computation effort, that all eigenvalues are zero (using the hint, but not taking it for granted!)  and how exactly thr Jordan form looks like. Your post totally missed that.

Comment: @MooS: The OP mentioned nothing about computation effort. It is trivial to verify that $A^4 = (A^2)^2 = 0$ (which is tantamount to what you have done in your answer) from which it follows that (i) the characteristic polynomial is $x \mapsto x^4$ and (ii) all eigenvalues are zero. This sort of pettiness is why my interest in helping out at MSE has significantly waned.